# MiKTeX encountered an internal error

Tags: miktex

When i click update wizard, it says "MiKTeX encountered an internal error."
This is why I can’t load any packages automatically.
What is the solution????

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you have enough disk space, you could install texlive instead of miktex. If you do a full texlive installation, you will have all package already installed and don't need to do any automatic package loading.

Comment: The question does not provide enough information for us to help you. Now, if others are suddenly encountering an internal error, that suggest a new problem with MiKTeX. But if it is just your system, we do not know why. I understand; I have occasionally asked a similar question (regarding Linux). Can you post more detail? What were you doing before you encountered the error? Have you looked at the MiKTeX site, to see if other users have your problem?

Comment: MikTex no longer supports Windows 7. If your system is Win7 the error message stated appears. The classic method is the "fix" which is to add the necessary sty files, or other files, in the folder where the work is saved.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (only possible!) that this is a temporary issue with TeXlive databases.

TeXlive was updated from 2022 to 2023 within the past week. Normally, a TeXlive 2022 user (including MiKTeX, if that version) will get a message saying that TeXlive is frozen for 2022, so no updates are available.

I just tried the Linux equivalent to MiKTeX update. Instead of the usual frozen message, I get an error saying that cryptographic signatures are wrong. That is unusual.

This suggests that there is a temporary problem with the package databases.
If so, it is the kind of thing that will "sooner or later" be fixed by the mirrors.

Comment: It is quite improbable that some texlive issue, gives a MiKTeX error message. MiKTeX is another tex system and not a part of texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Does MiKTeX not get component packages from CTAN mirrors? Not the binaries, the *sty and similar files. If it gets them from CTAN, I imagine that a mirror error might not be directly reported, but would indirectly trigger a MiKTeX error with a different message.